# How to fill area between several paths

Tags: intersections, fillbetween, path-clipping

I have the folling tikz code, where several paths intersect each other. I struggle to find a way to fill the six different regions of the resulting picture, each with a different pattern (not necessarily a plain color).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %used for theorem style
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (upleft) at (0,0);
\coordinate[right = 12cm of upleft] (upright);
\coordinate[below = 14cm of upright] (downright);
\coordinate[below = 14cm of upleft] (downleft);

\draw[name path=UP] (upleft) -- (upright);
\draw[name path=RIGHT] (upright) -- (downright);
\draw[name path=DOWN] (downright) -- (downleft);
\draw[name path=LEFT] (downleft) -- (upleft);

\coordinate[above right = 8cm and 6cm of downleft] (halt);
\coordinate[right = 2.5cm of upleft] (coneupleft);
\coordinate[left = 2.5cm of upright] (coneupright);
\coordinate[right = 4cm of downleft] (conedownleft);
\coordinate[left = 4cm of downright] (conedownright);

%left to right Curve
\coordinate[below = 2cm of upleft] (curve1left);
\coordinate[below = 2cm of upright] (curve1right);
\coordinate[below = 4cm of halt] (curve1middle);
\coordinate[left = 3cm of halt] (curve1middle1);
\coordinate[right = 3cm of halt] (curve1middle2);
\draw[name path=HIGH] (curve1left) to [curve through = {(curve1middle1) (curve1middle) (curve1middle2)}] (curve1right);

%up to bottom curves
\coordinate[right = 1cm of upleft] (vcurve1upl);
\coordinate[left = 1cm of upright] (vcurve1upr);
\coordinate[left = 3cm of conedownleft] (vcurve1bottoml);
\coordinate[right = 3cm of conedownright] (vcurve1bottomr);
\coordinate[left = 3.5cm of halt] (vcurve1ml);
\coordinate[right = 3.5cm of halt] (vcurve1mr);
\draw[name path=DNCLEFT] (vcurve1upl) to [curve through = {(vcurve1ml)}] (vcurve1bottoml);
\draw[name path=DNCRIGHT] (vcurve1upr) to [curve through = {(vcurve1mr)}] (vcurve1bottomr);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The goal is to fill the six regions with different patterns, if possible without touching the existing code, but only by adding new lines of code.

From what I could see looking at various similar questions, there may be a possibility with a combination of pieces of code like:

```tex
\fill[orange, intersection segments={
                of=HIGH and DNCLEFT,
                sequence={L2--R2}
              }];
```

However the above code is made to fill a pattern between two paths and not more. Also I do not understand the meaning of `L2` and `R2` (which apparently could also range from `R0` to `R2` or `L0` to `L2`, and used with some `reverse` keyword), so I have trouble mixing them together to achieve what I want.

Note that the full picture I'm working with has much more regions than the one I'm giving here, which is sort of a minimal exemple.

Ideally a combination of some clipping command of the form "*clip everything to the left/right/top/bottom* of a given path*" would be great, but I could not find how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the intersection segments to a new path that you can use for another `fillbetween` with yet another path, and so on. But here maybe simple clips are easier to deal with. You can use the `insert path` key to avoid unnecessary repetition. `intersections` is not needed here, but I kept all the `name path` keys in.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %used for theorem style
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (upleft) at (0,0);
\coordinate[right = 12cm of upleft] (upright);
\coordinate[below = 14cm of upright] (downright);
\coordinate[below = 14cm of upleft] (downleft);

\draw[name path=UP] (upleft) -- (upright);
\draw[name path=RIGHT] (upright) -- (downright);
\draw[name path=DOWN] (downright) -- (downleft);
\draw[name path=LEFT] (downleft) -- (upleft);

\coordinate[above right = 8cm and 6cm of downleft] (halt);
\coordinate[right = 2.5cm of upleft] (coneupleft);
\coordinate[left = 2.5cm of upright] (coneupright);
\coordinate[right = 4cm of downleft] (conedownleft);
\coordinate[left = 4cm of downright] (conedownright);

%left to right Curve
\coordinate[below = 2cm of upleft] (curve1left);
\coordinate[below = 2cm of upright] (curve1right);
\coordinate[below = 4cm of halt] (curve1middle);
\coordinate[left = 3cm of halt] (curve1middle1);
\coordinate[right = 3cm of halt] (curve1middle2);
\tikzset{HIGH/.style={insert path={(curve1left) to [curve through = {(curve1middle1) (curve1middle) (curve1middle2)}] (curve1right)}}}
\draw[name path=HIGH,HIGH] ;

%up to bottom curves
\coordinate[right = 1cm of upleft] (vcurve1upl);
\coordinate[left = 1cm of upright] (vcurve1upr);
\coordinate[left = 3cm of conedownleft] (vcurve1bottoml);
\coordinate[right = 3cm of conedownright] (vcurve1bottomr);
\coordinate[left = 3.5cm of halt] (vcurve1ml);
\coordinate[right = 3.5cm of halt] (vcurve1mr);
\tikzset{DNCLEFT/.style={insert path={(vcurve1upl) to [curve through = {(vcurve1ml)}] (vcurve1bottoml)}},
DNCRIGHT/.style={insert path={(vcurve1upr) to [curve through = {(vcurve1mr)}] (vcurve1bottomr)}}}
\draw[name path=DNCLEFT,DNCLEFT] ;
\draw[name path=DNCRIGHT,DNCRIGHT];
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \begin{scope}
  \fill[orange,HIGH] -- (upright) -- (upleft) -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}
  \fill[cyan,HIGH] -- (downright) -- (downleft) -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[DNCLEFT] -- (downleft)  |- (upleft) -| cycle;
  \fill[red,HIGH] --  (upright) -- (upleft) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[DNCRIGHT] -- (downright)  -- (upright) -| cycle;
  \fill[blue,HIGH] -- (upright) -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[DNCLEFT] -- (downleft)  |- (upleft) -| cycle;
  \fill[magenta,HIGH] -- (downright) -- (downleft) -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[DNCRIGHT] -- (downright)  -- (upright) -| cycle;
  \fill[purple,HIGH] -- (downright) -- (downleft) -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for !