# How to paint between smooth line and other line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to paint between smooth line and other line.
I typed following code.

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.5);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\coordinate (D) at (4,2);
\draw[thick](0,2.5)--(4,2.5);
\draw[thick]plot[smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {(O)(A)(B)(C)(D)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to paint yellow area like following figure.
Thank you.
[image]

The figure is just an image.
I want to paint along the smooth line, not along the jagged line as shown in the figure.

Comment: You want steps like that with gaps? Is there any pattern to it?

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `fillbetween` library that comes with the `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.5);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\coordinate (D) at (4,2);
\draw[thick, name path=A] (0,2.5) -- (4,2.5);
\draw[thick, name path=B] plot[smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(O) (A) (B) (C) (D)};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[yellow, intersection segments={of=A and B, sequence={L1 -- R1[reverse]}}] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use the `intersections` library:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.5);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\coordinate (D) at (4,2);
\draw[thick, name path=A] (0,2.5) -- (4,2.5);
\draw[thick, name path=B] plot[smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(O) (A) (B) (C) (D)};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \clip plot[smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(O) (A) (B) (C) (D)} |- (0,3) -- cycle;
    \fill[yellow, name intersections={of=A and B}] (intersection-1) rectangle (0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To avoid repetitive code, you could make use of the `insert code` option (as suggested [in this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575899/47927)):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, backgrounds}

\tikzset{draw curve/.style={insert path={
    plot[smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(O) (A) (B) (C) (D)}
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.5);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\coordinate (D) at (4,2);
\draw[thick, name path=A] (0,2.5) -- (4,2.5);
\draw[thick, name path=B, draw curve];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \clip[draw curve] |- (0,3) -- cycle;
    \fill[yellow, name intersections={of=A and B}] (intersection-1) rectangle (0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: About repetitive code: I had the same thoughts when [answering a previous Q by OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/690901). A softpath via `save path` is also an option as it doesn't evaluate the path again and is also immune against transformations. A [previous version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/690913/2) used `insert path` as well. Though, `fill between` is probably the best general approach anyway.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I first though that a solution with `save path` and `use path` would maybe work, but, as far as I know, you cannot continue the path when using `use path`, so this would not work here, because you would need to extend the path upwards to fill the part above the curve.

Comment: I see now that I clipped the rectangle and filled the curve, you clip the curve and fill the rectangle. That switch makes `insert path` necessary, yes.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But I think it does not really matter what is clipped and what is filled. The point is that in the linked example, the filled path of the curve already covers the area to be eventually filled. In this example here, this is not the case since filling the path of the curve would result in an area below the curve. Hence, you would need to add another coordinate above the curve in order to create the required area, and I am unsure whether this would work with `use path`.